# How to retrieve Django model object using ForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am new to Django and I am having dificulty of understanding how search Querys and work. I have these models:

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class List(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ListShared(models.Model):
    shared_list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="shared_list")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sub_user")
```

Idea is that single user can have any number of lists and share those lists to other users if they choose to do so.

I am trying write three querys:

1. Return all `List`s created by user
2. Return all `List`s that are shared to user
3. Return all above

So far it seems that 1. can be achieved with :

```
parent = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
lists = parent.list_set.all()
```

and 2. with:

```
lists = ListShared.objects.filter(user__exact=user)
```

But I can't seems to find a way to return every that user is connected to (3.). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with [**`Q`** objects <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q):

```
from django.db.models import Q

List.objects.filter(Q(user=parent) | Q(shared_list__user=parent))
```

or if you do not need to fetch the `User` object itself, you can work with the `user_name` directly with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

List.objects.filter(Q(user__username=user_name) | Q(shared_list__user__username=user_name))
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly. Only ``.distinct()`` is needed to ad at the end of the query to remove duplicate ``List``s. Thank you.